# Git rebase with forking

Tags: git, github

I am reading this about article about forking:

https://timonweb.com/misc/how-to-update-a-forked-repo-from-an-upstream-with-git-rebase-or-merge/

Listing the following steps:

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/django/django.git
```

2. Download master branch from upstream:

   git fetch upstream master
3. Overwrite your master with upstream's master via git rebase:

   git rebase upstream/master
4. Push to master, please note --force here:

   git push origin master --force

I do not understand Step 3: If i rebase, i put my master branch on top of the upstream/master.

In step 4) i am pushing origin master, but since i only updated origin/master and put my changes on top of it, i do not understand why this would change anything.

Additionally to my confusion, it says below, that you can do everything with merging as well.

What do i understand wrong here?

Comment: _"Overwrite your master with upstream's master via git rebase"_ - this isn't what rebase does. --- _"If i rebase, i put my master branch on top of the upstream/master."_ - exactly

Answer (score 1):

This is upstream:

```
A->B->C
```

This is master:

```
A->E->F
```

What `git rebase upstream/master` does is:

```
A->B->C->E'->F'
```

Note the **'**, their meaning is that the diff between `E` and it's parent is the same as the diff between `E'` and it's parent (if there was no conflict in the rebase operation), so one can say that those commits *contains the same thing*¹, hence we give them a similar name.

**But** `E` and  `E'` doesn't have the same parent, and because the parent hash is used to compute the commit hash (it's a block chain, Merkel tree), `E` and  `E'` doesn't have the same hash, hence are different commits, and therefore, `F` and  `F'` are different commits, etc...

So basically a rebase doesn't change the (diff from parent of the) commits that are on top, but because the block chain is not the same below, the hashes are not the same.

The merge introduce a node with two parents (`C` and `F`). Fun fact, git support nodes with n parents.

[1] It's a misunderstanding caused by the fact that commits are represented by diff to the parent, in fact a commit contains the full repo.

Answer (score -1):

Ah, i think i understand. I just put my commits on top of the current master.

I think, i got a bit mixed up. I interpreted the the upstream/master as a remote branch, but it is not, it is just another branch, which gets its commit from another source than origin/master.

Origin and upstream have both remote branches, but i am not rebasing on them but on their local counterpart (e.g. remote/upstream/master)

This was my confusion.

Comment: `upstream/master` aka `remotes/upstream/master` is indeed a counter part of a branch on a remote repo (last known state), to update it, you have to use `git push upstream`, same for `origin`. In most use cases there is only one remote and no ambiguity, `git push` is enough. In some cases, branch and remote repo have the same name. Hence the use of `remote/` for disambiguation.